# Apache Spark Scala

Tags: apache-spark-sql, user-defined-functions

Apologies if it very obvious question as i am newbie in Spark. I have defined a function in Scala and created a udf but how can i run the same udf on multiple columns. It seems withColumn can be used with just one column. Any pointers will be greatly appreciated. Morever, how can i use lambda functions ( Scala's USP) on DataSet/ DataFrames ?

```
    def stringConvertor(prefix: String) : Double = {

    prefix.takeRight(1) match {
      case "k" => prefix.reverse.substring(1).reverse.toDouble * 1000
      case "m" => prefix.reverse.substring(1).reverse.toDouble * 1000000
      case "n" => prefix.reverse.substring(2).reverse.toDouble * 1000000000
      case "%" => prefix.reverse.substring(1).reverse.toDouble / 100
      case ")" => prefix.dropRight(1).drop(1).toDouble * -1
      case "0" | "1" | "2" | "3" | "4" | "5" | "6" | "7" | "8" | "9" => prefix.toDouble
      case _   => 0
    }

  }

  val udfStringtoNumber = udf((s : String) => stringConvertor(s))


  val parseString = udf(sp)

  val spark = SparkSession.builder
      .appName("Spark SQL basic example")
      .config("spark.some.config.option", "some-value")
      .master("local")
      .getOrCreate()

  val df = spark.read.option("delimiter" , "|").option("header","true").option("inferSchema","true")
                    .csv("FileName.csv")
  //df.printSchema()

  import spark.implicits._

  val newdf = df.withColumn("TradeCCY", parseString($"PriceCCY"))
  val newDF = df.withColumn("CAvgVolume", udfStringtoNumber($"AvgVolume") )
```

Comment: `df.withColumn("TradeCCY", parseString($"PriceCCY")).withColumn("CAvgVolume", udfStringtoNumber($"AvgVolume") )` ?

Comment: Thanks i didn't relaise withColumn can be chained. Is there a way it can be done programatically .i.e. adding multiple  columns